# What would an acceptable replacement be for a discontinued Motorola HCT174A?

Tags: flipflop, soic

I am trying to replace a Hex D Flip-Flop on an Amiga A4000 motherboard.  The original chip has the label

```
HCT174A
XAA346
```

[image: Motorola HCT174A]

I believe the datasheet describing this is the [MC74HCT174A](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/4356/MOTOROLA/MC74HCT174A.html) (though I can't find a reference to the `XAA346`), however, a BOM for the Amiga Motherboard lists

```
74HCT174, SOIC package
74HCT174, SM, EIAJ Package (as an subsititue)
```

When when I search Mouser.com I find [5 possible choices](https://www.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Logic-ICs/Flip-Flops/_/N-55d5e?Keyword=74HCT174%20SOIC&FS=True) and the [TI CD74HCT174M](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/CD74HCT174M?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvxP%252bvr8KwMwD64K6n%252b0blWpUBIr7RET4I%3D) ([datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hct174.pdf)) seems like the correct choice, is there anything to keep in mind when sourcing a replacement?

Comment: What did that? battery acid? all the copper is gone, it looks very hard to repair.

Comment: yeah battery acid, I actually have a reprinted A4000 D Rev. B motherboard that I am transferring the non-damaged original chips over to.  Amazingly when I received this motherboard it actually booted with this damage, though some diagnostic software suggested it was slower than Amiga 5000 so I'm sure some bizarre things were going on inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

74HCTxxx is a standard logic family (just as 74HCxxx, 74LSxxx, 74ALSxxx, etc.)

All manufacturers were supposed to abide to the same nomenclature, input and output logic levels, fan-in, fan-out, and timing.

Parts within the same family are supposed to be manufacturer-independent.

Furthermore, 74HCT parts were designed to interoperate with both 74HC and 74LS parts, to give more freedom to the designer.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking at is indeed a 74HCT174. This is a standard logic IC, so TI's version of the part (which you've found) should be perfectly acceptable. Hardware makers of the time would frequently substitute equivalent parts from different manufacturers -- notice the Philips 74HCT166 right above it, for instance.

The "XAA346" on the second line is a manufacturing code or lot number -- properly decoded, it can probably be used to determine when and where that specific IC was manufactured. You can safely ignore it.

Comment: Both answers were very helpful, so I ended up selecting based on time answered (though even that was close), but I wanted to still express my thanks :)